# mPDF generated PDF is only working in Firefox

Tags: php, mpdf

So I was using the mPDF PHP library to generate a PDF using HTML code. I finished my code and then I realized that it only works in Firefox, for example in Chrome it displays 'Failed to load PDF document'.

Then I used the code from the examples instead of my own code and the same thing happens. Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

```
<?php
ob_start();
include('plugins/mpdf/mpdf.php');
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>Hello World</p>');
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```

Comment: The code you posted should work on both Firefox as well as Chrome. Post the Chrome version. Is it the case that the pdf file is being downloaded correctly but Chrome fails to open it?

Comment: I solved the problem! I was missing ob_clean(); some PDF readers ignored the html while others become corrupt, it has nothing to do with browsers. Thanks

Comment: I tried using ob_clean(). But the same problem showing.. Failed to load pdf document... Can you please help me to sort this.

Comment: It appears like that in all browsers? Try to open the pdf with notepad++ and see if there is html stuff in the code from your webpage, if it shows then it is causing the problem. The first line should be something like %PDF-1.4

Comment: It is possible that you have a space (" ") or new line "\n" after ?> or before <?php also it is possible that the header from mpdf is not correct, witch version you are using?

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue but I got solution..
First remove ob_start(), and then put ob_clean() at that place.

```
ob_clean();
include('plugins/mpdf/mpdf.php');
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>Hello World</p>');
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

Comment: as simple as that :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.I was adding header.php before calling mpdf.php and it did not work.After removing it is working fine.